# How do I minus quantity from mysql table using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I have an item stored in warehouse. I have

```
| id_ware | id_item | qty|
| :------ | :------ |:---|
| Lab     | 103     | 20 |
```

I want to minus that quantity in that row, so if I enter 2 in textbox and press the button exit, the qty will be 18.

I tried this:

```
public void minusQuantity(string store, string product, int quantity)
{
    con.Open();

    int newQty;

    string sql = "SELECT qty FROM Item,Warehouse,stocker WHERE stocker.code_en=Warehouse.code_en AND stocker.code=Item.code AND Warehouse.code_en='" + store + "' AND Item.code='" + product + "' ";

    MySqlDataReader reader = null;

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        newQty = Convert.ToInt32(reader["qty"]) - quantity;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update stocker set stock_theo='" + newQuantity + "' WHERE code_en='" + depot + "' AND code='" + item + "' ", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("updated row.");
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

It doesn't work there is an error. so What else can I do please if you have suggestion?

Comment: "It doesn't work there is an error" - Please elaborate and include these details in your post. It makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Please look into PARAMETERIZED QUERIES.  Do NOT do concatenation of a SQL command.  You get into big trouble, especially if web-based for SQL-Injection.

Comment: It says that I cannot executeReader and then ExecuteQuery while I am reading the data in database.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I can use executeNonQuery while I am using executedatareader. My plan is to take the value from database and and update it.

Comment: you don't need the select it is not necessary at all, mysql can count fine by uit self  and see how prepared statements work

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to S/O, I have rewritten your query using proper context of parameterized queries.  Heavily commented through to show you what is going on.  I personally do not have MySQL prepared on my machine, but the syntax appears correct after I installed the MySQL package manager.

```
        public void minusQuantity(string store, string product, int quantity)
        {
            // I have no idea where your "con" object is, but assuming some property of the class
            con.Open();

            int newQty;

            // Dont build concatenated strings for SQL-based queries via Select, Insert, Update, etc.
            // Parameterize them.  In MySQL, parameters are identified by using a "?parmName" context

            // start just creating the command object
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", con);

            // Now, set the command text readable and showing "?" where the parameters will be
            command.CommandText =
@"SELECT 
        qty 
    FROM 
        Item,
        Warehouse,
        stocker 
    WHERE 
            stocker.code_en = Warehouse.code_en 
        AND stocker.code = Item.code 
        AND Warehouse.code_en = ?parmStore
        AND Item.code = ?parmProduct 
";

            // Now, add the two parameters to the command.  the "?" is so the .net knows 
            // it will be found in a parameter.  I have the parameters prefixed with "parm"
            // for the SOLE PURPOSE of knowing its a parameter name and not to be confused
            // with some other column name of a table and cause confusion.  The VALUE that
            // is being set is rather obvious from the parameters coming into your function
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmStore", store);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmProduct", product);

            // Now we can work on the reader
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Ok, you are computing the new quantity
                newQty = Convert.ToInt32(reader["qty"]) - quantity;

                // Now, we need to do the same for the SQL-UPDATE.  Prepare it, and parameters too
                var updCmd = new MySqlCommand("", con);
                updCmd.CommandText =
@"update stocker set 
        stock_theo = ?parmFinalQty
    where
            code_en = ?parmStore
        AND code = ?parmProduct";

                // Now, you can see and read relatively clearly the SQL-Update command
                // setting the stock to the new value WHERE the given code/item
                // NOW, you need to add the parameters to your command object
                updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmFinalQty", newQty);
                updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmStore", store);
                updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmProduct", product);

                updCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("updated row.");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Does your code work? Are  you sure it won't throw `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command` or something like that?

Answer (score -2):

```
public void minusQuantity(string store, string product, int quantity)
{
    con.Open();
    int newQty;
    string sql = "SELECT qty FROM Item,Warehouse,stocker WHERE stocker.code_en=Warehouse.code_en AND stocker.code=Item.code AND Warehouse.code_en='" + store + "' AND Item.code='" + product + "' ";
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        newQty = Convert.ToInt32(reader["qty"]) - quantity;
        MySqlConnection con2 = ...;//create second connection here
        con2.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update stocker set stock_theo='" + newQuantity + "' WHERE code_en='" + depot + "' AND code='" + item + "' ", con2);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con2.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("updated row.");
        
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: very bad example... you are immediately doing a concatenated query which is VERY BAD PRACTICE.